# Hiding winforms app from taskbar

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I hide a winform, so that it t will not show in the Windows taskbar , user do not see it , or when the user presses <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In code do the following:

`this.ShowInTaskbar = false;`

Or in Design mode:

[image]

EDIT:

You must also set the FormBorderStyle

Code:

`this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;`

Design:

[image]

This definitely does work - these are some screen prints using Windows Vista.

App running:

[image]

Not appearing in ALT + TAB

[image]

Comment: this way do not hide winform from Alt + Tab

Comment: Or set FormBorderStyle to FixedToolWindow if you don't want the form to be sizable.

Comment: How can I do this in VS2012?  I don't know if it makes a difference.  I'm using a User Control and wrapping it in the form.  I don't see the option for `FormBorderStyle`. I see `BorderStyle` with three options:  `None`, `FixedSingle`, and `Fixed3D`.

Comment: When I try anything except `None` it throws an error when trying to add a child panel to the form.  The error says that the `Value cannot be Null`.  The debugger shows me that `this.panel1` is null...

Answer (score 8):

To hide your form from the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> dialog, add this code into your form's class:

```
// Remove from Alt+Tab dialog
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        var Params = base.CreateParams;
        Params.ExStyle |= 0x80;
        return Params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good solution, just note this will also hide it in the task manager applications list.

Comment: I vote positive because it hiddes in the task manager